# Zend_Form_Element ignore flag not working?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I learnt that I can set the `ignore` flag on a `Zend_Form_Element` so that it's ignored when getting values etc.

I have

```
$this->addElement('submit', 'btnLogin', array(
    'label' => 'Login',
    'ignore' => true
));
```

But when I do

```
foreach ($this->getElements() as $elem) {
    echo $elem->getName() . "<br />";
}
```

It stills includes the `btnLogin`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `ignore`-flag will only ensure that the form element <del>does not get a `name`-attribute effectively removing it from the posted form data</del> is not included when retrieving the form values on the form level (`$form->getValues()`). You won't get the element's value when doing e.g.:

```
foreach ($form->getValues() as $name => $value) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: hmm i am still getting `<input type="submit" value="Login" id="btnLogin" name="btnLogin">`

Comment: You're right... I mixed up the `ignore`-handling in Zend Framework and ExtJS - stupid... `ignore` will only ensure that the element's values is not included when retrieving the data on the form level (`$form->getValues()`). I'll adjust my answer accordingly.

Comment: Also note that if you have an element that is required and then set the disabled property to true (for example, if you wanted to disable a form element that is not allowed to be changed because of ACL), you must also change required to false.  Setting ignore does not override the element's required setting.